# How to CCAvanue payment getway intigrate in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Hello Developers please help me ..
 I have Already CCAvanue payment getway integrate in laravel .. i was problem payment and bill payment is work then any option payment choose but then submit this screen show

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel package indipay. It supports gateways like CCAvenue, PayUMoney, EBS, CitrusPay ,ZapakPay (Mobikwik), Mocker

https://github.com/softon/indipay

http://softon.github.io/indipay/